# Ĉu ekzistas Esperanto-nomo por "Daddy Long-Legs"?

Tags: translation

Mi scivolas ĉu ekzistas esperantigo por la araneo angle konata kiel "Daddy Long-Legs". Jen artikolo (en la angla) temanta pri ĝi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pholcidae

Ĉi tia araneo abundas en Aŭstralio kaj strange mi ofte devas priparoli ĝin.

Answer (score 7):

La [vortaro de John Wells](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) havas ĉi tion:

> **daddy longlegs** *(crane fly, insect)* tipulo; *(harvestman, arachnid)* falangio

Mi ne certas ĉu tio helpas aŭ ne, ĉar la angla vorto ŝajnas tre nebula. Ŝajne *daddy long-legs* povas esti tri diversaj aferoj. Se la afero kiun vi volas vere estas araneo, eble *falangio* plej taŭgas. Tamen laŭ ReVo tio estas nur “arane-simila”.

Estas tente inventi simile nebulan vorton en esperanto, ekzemple *longkrurulo*.

Comment: La [vikipedia taksonomio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taksonomio_de_araneoj) subtenas la terminon `falangio`.

Comment: Temas pri ĉi tiu araneo: https://australianmuseum.net.au/learn/animals/spiders/daddy-long-legs-spider/
Do, la speco estas phalangioides. Ĉu tio estas falangio? Mi ne bone komprenas taksonomion.